# in python multiple commands using su - user

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to run commands after running `su - username`
I tried to use:

```
subprocess.run(['su', '-', str(username)]) #username is var
subprocess.run(['touch', 'test.txt'])
```

or

```
run_su = 'su - '+ str(username) #username is var
os.system(run_su)
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['su', '-', str(username)]) #username is var
subprocess.call(['touch', 'test.txt'])
```

or

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['su', '-', str(username)], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #username is var
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['touch', 'test.txt'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

nothing seems to work for me.

can you suggest a way to do that?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Both the first and second variant work here, didn't test the rest. Obviously the `touch` command will not be executed until the shell you start with `su` is terminated, and it will *not* be executed by the `su` process. You need to pass the command to be executed to `su`.

Why not use a sehllscript?

Comment: Probably the easiest thing is to throw the sequence of commands into a temporary file and run *that* file with sudo. Subprocesses in Python are run in separate shells (and, depending on how you invoke them, may not even involve a shell directly)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I don't get the test.txt file on the username directory like I'm doing it on shell. I don't see the test.txt file anywhere.

Comment: @Barak The text file will appear after the `su` command terminates, since it tries to open a new shell. It will either terminate by closing that shell, or by typing a wrong password.

Comment: @Barak there's another way to go about this if you want to create a file that is owned by a specific user. You can just create the file directly and `chown` the file to the desired user.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar I probably didn't explained myself very good
When using the `su - username` command on linux shell, it changes the work dir to that user work dir. and then I want the file to be created on that work dir or environment.

Comment: in that case, you can run the command as `su -c <command> <username>`. However, unless you are `root` you will run into a password prompt for the target user.

Answer (score 2):

managed to do this with creating a var

```
demo = "su -l username -c 'command as string'"
os.system(str(demo))
```